# c:forEach inside p:tab does not work

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jstl

I am using primefaces 6, JSf2.0, jstl 1.2 on Weblogic server.
I have an xhtml page where i want to display panels dynamically inside a Tab. The panels should behave like a Dashboard, so i have put the panels inside a dashboard tag.

My problem is that `c:forEach` is not able to get values from the items I want to iterate. It is confirmed that my "items="${cg.charts}" is of List type and does have objects, but the panels dont appear in UI, as well as there are not exception raised. Any leads ?

```
<p:tabView  id="tabViewId"
value="#{userdashboard.chartGroupsList}" var="cg" onTabShow="reflowChart()" >


<p:tab title="#{cg.groupName}" >



    <p:dashboard model="#{userdashboard.model}" >
    <p:ajax event="reorder" listener="#{userdashboard.handleReorder}"  />


    <c:forEach var="c" items="${cg.charts}">


       <p:panel id="pnlDivId#{c.id}" header="#{c.name}">hello</p:panel>





    </c:forEach>

    </p:dashboard>
</p:tab>

</p:tabView>
```

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense) first. This is not p:tab related, it is a generic issue. You cannot access variables of jsf tags in jstl tags.

Comment: if i use ui:repeat, instead of c:forEach, i get a ClassCastException , saying that UI repeat cannot be casted to Panel tag.

Comment: can anyone help ?

Comment: the dashboard should be defined in the model. Like in the showcase

Comment: the dashboard in my example is using model. <p:dashboard model="#{userdashboard.model}" >

Comment: Sorry, yes, the model in for the dashboard is only for the order, contrary to other components that use a 'model'.

Comment: @Kukeltje . how can i solve the ClassCastException which is raised when i use ui:repeat ?

Comment: Only by changing the internals of the dashboard. I think you ran into a corner case that is not supported.

Comment: Thank you. Now i have a clear way to decide.